# What is the multiplication rate in FIR filter

Tags: filters, sampling, lowpass-filter, finite-impulse-response, multirate

Consider a system implementing a rational sampling rate change by 5/7: for this, we cascade upsampler by 5, a lowpass filter with cutoff frequency pi/7 and a downsampler by 7. The lowpass filter is a 99-tap FIR.

Assume that the input works at a rate of 1000 samples per second. What is the number of multiplications per second required by the system? Assume that multiplications by zero do not count and round the number of operations to the nearest integer.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: this question was asked before, and I provided an answer for it.... Are you the same guy with a different name or another guy taking the same quiz ? ;-)

Comment: another taking the same quiz , Would you please help me ? @Fat32

Comment: For homework questions, we ask you to **show your work**, and then we'll show you where you're going astray.  As a hint, ask yourself how many multiplications you need for one sample of a 99-tap filter, then ask what the sampling rate is.